# Java fatal runtime error while loading texture in LWJGL

Tags: java, crash, lwjgl

My program is crashing due to an `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` in the file `ig7icd64.dll` file.

I'm creating a simple project with the LWJGL library and some external jars found here: https://github.com/CodingAP/LWJGL-3-Tutorial.git (just using slick-util3) and when loading textures from resource files ('.png') the program crashes.

I have many classes which are using a lot of GLXX.gl[function_name_here],
but I will explain why I do not list all of them.

I create a window with a Window class which just sets up a GLFW-context and works just fine.

I have a Model class which gets extended by UntexturedModel as well as TexturedModel. These set up VertexArrays and VertexBuffers and function normally.
I even have a Shader class which reads two shader files and applies them with no errors.

```
public class UntexturedModel extends Model {

private int vertexArrayID, vertexBufferID, indicesBufferID, vertexCount;

public UntexturedModel(float[] vertices, int[] indices) {
    vertexArrayID = super.createVertexArray();
    indicesBufferID = super.bindIndicesBuffer(indices);
    vertexBufferID = super.storeData(0, 3, vertices);
    vertexCount = indices.length;
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
}

public void destroy () {
    GL30.glDeleteVertexArrays(vertexArrayID);
    GL15.glDeleteBuffers(vertexBufferID);
    GL15.glDeleteBuffers(indicesBufferID);
}

// I have not included the getters for the IDs due to the space available
}
```

This extends the Model class which follows:

```
public class Model {

protected int createVertexArray() {
    int vertexArrayID = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayID);
    return vertexArrayID;
}

protected int storeData (int attributeNumber, int coordSize, float[] data) {

    FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(data.length);
    buffer.put(data);
    buffer.flip();

    int bufferID = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferID);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    return bufferID;
}

protected int bindIndicesBuffer (int[] indices) {

    IntBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(indices.length);
    buffer.put(indices);
    buffer.flip();

    int bufferID = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferID);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    return bufferID;
}
}
```

The TexturedModel is in essence the same as UntexturedModel, but has an additional float[] textureCoords which gets added using storeData(1, 2, textureCoords); It also has an attribute Material which uses the external jars:

```
public class Material {

private int textureID;

public Material (String file) {
    try {

        textureID = TextureLoader.getTexture("png", new FileInputStream("res/" + file)).getTextureID();
        // Possible error location: TextureLoader is an external jar

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: Couldn't load texture");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}

public void destroy () {
    GL11.glDeleteTextures(textureID);
}
// I'm ignoring getters once again
}
```

Using the UntexturedModel class works fine, even with shader files. I will include the BasicShader and Shader classes below:

```
public abstract class Shader {

private int vertexShaderID, fragmentShaderID, programID;
private String vertexFile, fragmentFile;

public Shader (String vertexFile, String fragmentFile) {
    this.vertexFile = vertexFile;
    this.fragmentFile = fragmentFile;
}

public void create () {
    programID = GL20.glCreateProgram();

    vertexShaderID = GL20.glCreateShader(GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    GL20.glShaderSource(vertexShaderID, readFile(vertexFile));
    GL20.glCompileShader(vertexShaderID);

    if (GL20.glGetShaderi(vertexShaderID, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL11.GL_FALSE) {
        System.err.println("Error: Vertex Shader - " + GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShaderID));
    }

    fragmentShaderID = GL20.glCreateShader(GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    GL20.glShaderSource(fragmentShaderID, readFile(fragmentFile));
    GL20.glCompileShader(fragmentShaderID);

    if (GL20.glGetShaderi(fragmentShaderID, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL11.GL_FALSE) {
        System.err.println("Error: Fragment Shader - " + GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShaderID));
    }

    GL20.glAttachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
    GL20.glAttachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);

    GL20.glLinkProgram(programID);

    if (GL20.glGetProgrami(programID, GL20.GL_LINK_STATUS) == GL11.GL_FALSE) {
        System.err.println("Error: Program Linking - " + GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(programID));
    }

    GL20.glValidateProgram(programID);

    if (GL20.glGetProgrami(programID, GL20.GL_VALIDATE_STATUS) == GL11.GL_FALSE) {
        System.err.println("Error: Program Validation - " + GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(programID));
    }
}

public abstract void bindAllAttributes();

public void bindAttribute (int index, String location) {
    GL20.glBindAttribLocation(programID, index, location);
}

public void bind () {
    GL20.glUseProgram(programID);
}

public void destroy () {
    GL20.glDetachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
    GL20.glDetachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);

    GL20.glDeleteShader(vertexShaderID);
    GL20.glDeleteShader(fragmentShaderID);

    GL20.glDeleteProgram(programID);
}

private String readFile (String path) {
    BufferedReader reader;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    try {

        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));

        String line = reader.readLine();

        while (line != null) {

            builder.append(line + '\n');
            line = reader.readLine();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: Exception while reading from file");
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
}

public class BasicShader extends Shader {

private static final String VERTEX_FILE = ".\\src\\shaders\\basicVertexShader.vs";
private static final String FRAGMENT_FILE = ".\\src\\shaders\\basicFragmentShader.fs";

public BasicShader() {
    super(VERTEX_FILE, FRAGMENT_FILE);
}

@Override
public void bindAllAttributes () {
    super.bindAttribute(0, "position");
    super.bindAttribute(1, "textCoords");
}
}
```

I've tested the shader files (basicVertexShader.vs and basicFragmentShader.fs) and they work as intended.

I have tried the following:
    Seeing if the .dll file was deleted.
    Re-installing Java (jdk and jre included)
    Re-installing Eclipse
    Updating Graohics Driver to the by Intel suggested verion

I'm using Windows 10 and a Lenovo Thinkpad.

If any additional information is needed, please ask bellow.

Update:

Stack: [0x0000000002b10000,0x0000000002c10000],  sp=0x0000000002c0bf40,  free space=1007k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)

C  [ig7icd64.dll+0x933b0]

C  [ig7icd64.dll+0x17b4b2]

C  [ig7icd64.dll+0x215514]

C  [ig7icd64.dll+0x6d1ee]

C  [ig7icd64.dll+0x243745]

C  [ig7icd64.dll+0x92555]

C  [ig7icd64.dll+0x2a3af8]

C  [ig7icd64.dll+0x2a3e09]

C  [ig7icd64.dll+0x2a57ba]

C  0x0000000002d88c67

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)

j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11C.nglDrawElements(IIIJ)V+0

j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11C.glDrawElements(IIIJ)V+4

j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glDrawElements(IIIJ)V+4

j  render.Renderer.renderTexturedModel(Lrender/TexturedModel;)V+43 (Renderer is a class which just executes the glDrawElements() function; nothing special)

j  main.Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+191

v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

Update:
I solved the issue. It lies in Model.storeData(). I don't use attributeNumber or coordSize. CLOSED

Comment: Thanks @httpdigest ! I just checked my bindings and the parameters and I messed some obvious numbers. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CLOSED] As you can see in my last edit, my error lies in the `Model` class. I don't actually use the `index` and `size` parameters in the `storeData()` function which means I'm trying to store the arrays in the same list so the program crashed. Thank you to everyone.